# How can I detect a click on a rotated image in Slick2D?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I have an image that I rotate before I draw.  The image is rotated by the angles of a hexagon.  In other words, the image basically "highlights" the individual edges of a hexagon.  I need to detect if the mouse was clicked inside of this rotated image.  Detecting a mouse click inside of an unrotated image is pretty simple, but I have no idea about how to detect clicks within rotated points.  Is there a way to get the points of the image's corners after rotation so I can place an invisible polygon on top of the image and use Polygon.contains()?

```
                    Image highlightEdge = new Image("assets/img/highlightEdge.png");
                    if(angle == 90){
                        highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(highlightEdge.getWidth(), 0);
                        highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));
                        highlightEdge.draw(testPoint.x - 56, testPoint.y);
                    } else if(angle == 210) {
                        highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(0, 0);
                        highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));
                        highlightEdge.draw(lastSettlement.x - 72, lastSettlement.y - 32);
                    } else if( angle == 330){
                        highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(0, 0);
                        highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));
                        highlightEdge.draw(lastSettlement.x - 8, lastSettlement.y - 32);
                    } else if(angle == 30){
                        highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(0, 0);
                        highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));
                        highlightEdge.draw(lastSettlement.x-8, lastSettlement.y);
                    } else if(angle == 150){
                        highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(0, 0);
                        highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));
                        highlightEdge.draw(lastSettlement.x-72, lastSettlement.y);
                    } else {
                        highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(0, 0);
                        highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));
                        highlightEdge.draw(lastSettlement.x-40, lastSettlement.y - 48);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Shape` to exactly match the shape of the `Image`, and then use its method `contains` to detect if the mouse was clicked inside.

To take in consideration the rotation of the `Image` you could apply a corresponding rotation `Transform` to the `Shape`.

I created the method `shapeFromImage` that does this; it receives an `Image` and its position and returns the corresponding `Shape`:

```
/**
 * Returns the Shape of an Image considering its rotation
 * @param image
 * @param x the x position of the Image
 * @param y the y position of the Image
 */
public static Shape shapeFromImage(Image image, float x, float y) {

    // create a rectangle with same position and size of the image
    Shape imageShape = new Rectangle(x, y, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());

    // get the rotation angle of the image
    float angle = image.getRotation();

    // if the image is rotated, we also need to rotate our shape 
    if (angle != 0.f) {

        // convert the rotation angle in radians to use in Transform 
        float angleInRadians = (float) Math.toRadians(angle);

        // get the point of rotation to use in Transform.
        // image.getCenterOfRotation returns a point relative to the image.
        // for Transform we need an absolute point, so we add the image position to it
        float rotationX = image.getCenterOfRotationX() + x;
        float rotationY = image.getCenterOfRotationY() + y;

        // create the rotation Transform to match the image rotation
        Transform rotationTransform = Transform.createRotateTransform(angleInRadians, rotationX, rotationY);

        // apply the rotation Transform to our shape
        imageShape = imageShape.transform(rotationTransform);

    }

    return imageShape;
}
```

In your example you could use it like this:

```
float positionX;
float positionY;

if (angle == 90) {
    highlightEdge.setCenterOfRotation(highlightEdge.getWidth(), 0);
    highlightEdge.rotate(new Float(angle));

    positionX = testPoint.x - 56;
    positionY = testPoint.y;

    highlightEdge.draw(positionX, positionY);
} 

...

// you can now use this Shape to use its method "contains"
imageShape = shapeFromImage(highlightEdge, positionX, positionY);
```